# Items displaying wrong from database using .InnerHtml

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to dynamically display textbooks from a database by category.

When I hardcoded the textbooks into the html using cards, the cards stacked side ways using a .gridcontainer where for every 4 items it will be in one row.

Now that i dynamically display the items the cards stack on top of each other and not side ways

I am trying to create a e-commerce book website and I'm doing the explore page which displays the books.

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslategray;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid blue 10px;

}
```

```
<h2>Mathematics</h2>
<div class="grid-container">

<span id="Maths" runat="server"></span>

</div>
```

```
dynamic products = SR.getProductByCat("mathematics");
string display = "";

foreach(TextBook p in products)
{
    display += "<div class='card'>";
    display += "<h3>" + p.Book_Name + "</h3>";

    display += "<a href='AboutProduct.aspx?ID=" + p.Book_ISBN + "'> <img src=' " + p.Book_ImageSource + "' style='width:50%' <a/>";

    display += "<p> R" + p.Book_Price.ToString("#.##") + "</p>";
    display += "<p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>";
    display += "</div>";
}

Maths.InnerHtml = display;
```

I expect the cards containing book information to display side ways but it stacks on top of each other

Comment: Post the rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

There's a small error in the closing tag of your href - it's possible that's messing up the whole page.

```
<a/>
```

should be

```
</a>
```

Always use an HTML validator to help spot minor mistakes like this.

Comment: Will give it go

Comment: Gave it a go ... still did not stack properly ... I tried a different approach with using row and column class division and that sorted the issue .. but thank you for responding

Comment: That's odd, I can't see anything else wrong - not that I'm much of an expert on the css grid. Typically I'd take the HTML generated by code like this and compare it to code that works (e.g. from a on-line example) and change one thing at a time to find the difference.